# How to redirect to a page in an iframe but should load as a different page?

Tags: php, html, redirect, iframe

I have called a iframe in a page and in the iframe there is a link when click should open another page. But when i use header tags in php it loads the page inside the iframe.
How can I resolve this issue?

Page 1:
`<iframe width="990" height="245" src="example2.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>`

Iframe - example.php?id= :

`<?php
    header ("Location: example3.php?class=<?php echo $_GET['classid']");
?>`

How can I redirect this page to another page without loading inside the iframe in page 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot using only PHP, but you could probably do something like this, using javascript:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href = "example3.php?class=' . $_GET['classid'] . '"; </script>' ?>
```

Also, you cannot nest PHP tags the way you are trying to do

Comment: what do you mean by nesting php tags?

Comment: @RuchinaPerera php tags inside of php tags, it doesn't work, look up concatenation.

Comment: then how to make the link dynamic. such as id=1 and id  = 2 in the other tab? we need to dynamic it by using php am i right?

Comment: Yes the thing is, you can't open a <?php tag inside another <?php tag. Also, this is not necessary. The code I posted in my answer is dynamic, it will insert the 'classid' GET parameter